# Limitar a 2 el número de decimales en Awk

Tags: awk

Tengo el siguiente comando awk para hacer la división de dos variables y necesito mostrar solo dos decimales al imprimir la variable de resultado:

```
Result=$(awk "BEGIN {print $var1/$var2}")
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Simplemente usa `printf` e indica `%.2f` para el número de decimales:

```
awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f \n", $var1/$var2}'
```

Ejemplo:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {v1=v2=1; printf "%.2f \n", v1/v2}'
1.00
```

Comment: He copiado eso cambiando var1 y var2 por mis variables y me da el siguiente error:awk: run time error:                                                                                   
not enough arguments passed to printf("%.2f 
-nan")
 FILENAME="" FNR=0 NR=0                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                        Pero cuando lo hago con mi comando si que me sale el resultado con muchos decimales.

Comment: @Gabriel64 disculpa, faltaba una coma. Nótese que estás usando dobles comillas y variables de Bash directamente en Awk, cosa que no es demasiado recomendable. Mejor pasar la variable diciendo `awk -v var1="$var" '.... var1'`.